# How do I parse 真的发展成男女朋友玩的来聊的开那还是要过个一年半载才能确定的 into English?

Tags: translation

The offending sentence (haha) is in bold below. Can't for the life of me figure out what is going on with it.

> 许多妹子都觉得刚失恋去找别的男人不太好，其实无所谓啦，**真的发展成男女朋友玩的来聊的开那还是要过个一年半载才能确定的**，先随便聊聊么，认识认识，没到考试的时候也可以在生活里多个出勤率，哪里跌倒就从哪里爬起来，越是被男人甩了越用自己的趣味和大方去和其他男人聊聊，对自己恢复（男女关系方面的）信心也没啥坏处。

Comment: How about adding some punctuation and helper words in? 眞的發展成男女朋友，到玩的來、聊的開的程度，那還是要。。。。。。

Comment: 真的发展成男女朋友,玩的来,聊的开,那还是要过个一年半载才能确定的

Answer (score 3):

许多妹子都觉得刚失恋去找别的男人不太好，
Many girls think looking for a new man just after breaking up is not a good idea,
其实无所谓啦，
actually, it doesn't matter
真的发展成男女朋友[玩得来聊得开]那还是要过个一年半载才能确定的，
to really become girlfriend and boyfriend, [have fun and chat openly], that will take about a year before you have a rapport,
先随便聊聊么，
first just chat,
认识认识，
get to know each other,
没到考试的时候也可以在生活里多个出勤率，
it's not exam time yet, you can also concentrate more on your life,
哪里跌倒就从哪里爬起来，
get up from where you have fallen down,
越是被男人甩了越用自己的趣味和大方去和其他男人聊聊，
the more you are rejected the more you should use your personality and magnanimity to talk with other men
对自己恢复（男女关系方面的）信心也没啥坏处。
this will help you recover your confidence (in male female relationships) and won't do you any harm.

Reader's Digest philosophy??

Answer (score 2):

[真的发展成] [男女朋友][玩的来][聊的开][那还是要过个一年半载][才能确定的]

the correct phrasing should be as follow:

"真的发展成玩的来、 聊的开的男女朋友, 那还是要过个一年半载才能确定的。"

The first sentence "真的发展成玩的来、 聊的开的男女朋友" (*to really develop into boyfriend-girlfriend relationship that you can play and talk freely with each other*) is the topic

The second sentence  "那还是要过个一年半载才能确定的。" (*that still need a year or so before you can be sure*) is the comment/opinion

Comment: Good answer; however, instead of calling your rewriting a "correct phrasing", I would just say that the quoted passage in the question is a literal transcription from speech to text, while your rewriting is the proper way to express the idea in writing. @user2137196, spoken Chinese put character-for-character in writing misses out essential information such as body language or mood cues, and you'll have to extrapolate what these are when you read such passages.